How to fix slick centerMode if the slidesToShow is less than the slick items
If the items are more than 6 the centerMode is working fine, but if the items is less than 6 slides doesn't center correctly.
I'm trying to implement a JS functionality that if the slide items in the html is less than 6 the centerMode will still working or disabled.
Im trying to follow this example but I cant replicate because the source site are not found:
Slick slider centermode not working when more slides than slidestoshow variable
Check my code below and you can also check the codepen here:
https://codepen.io/graydirt/full/vYMxpQE


$(function() {

  $('.slider-for').slick({
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    fade: true,
    asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
  });
  
// Set preferred slidesToShow
var slidesToShow = 5;
var childElements = $('.slider-nav').children().length;
// Check if we can fulfill the preferred slidesToShow
if( slidesToShow > (childElements-1) ) {
    // Otherwise, make slidesToShow the number of slides - 1
    // Has to be -1 otherwise there is nothing to scroll for - all the slides would already be visible
    slidesToShow = (childElements-1);
}
  
  $('.slider-nav').slick({
    slidesToShow: slidesToShow,
    /*slidesToShow: 5,*/
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    asNavFor: '.slider-for',
    dots: false,
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '70px',
    focusOnSelect: true,
    variableWidth: false,
    rows: 0,
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 992,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3,
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 576,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  
});
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.slider-style-for {
  & img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.slider-style-nav {
  & .slider-nav__items {
    width: 260px;
  }
  & .slick-next {
    right: 0;
  }
  & .slick-prev {
    left: 0;
  }
  & .slick-next:before, 
  & .slick-prev:before {
    color: black;
  }
}



div[aria-hidden="true"] img {
  opacity: .3;
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <div class="slider slider-for slider-style-for">
        <div>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
           <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="slider slider-nav slider-style-nav">
        <div class="m-2 slider-nav__items">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-1.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="m-2 slider-nav__items">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="m-2 slider-nav__items">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="m-2 slider-nav__items">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="m-2 slider-nav__items">
          <img src="https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




please create an example code where we can directly see the issue. Current code is working perfectly fine.

please check the code snippet above the code isn't working fine, theres an opacity on the full image if the items is less than 6. You can also check it here https://codepen.io/graydirt/full/vYMxpQE thanks.
